# Extracting values from a dict - flask and jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my template I have

```
<p>{% for dict_item in MySQL_Dict %}
   {% for key, value in dict_item.items() %}
    {{value}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}</p>
```

Which outputs `43.8934276 -103.3690243 47.052060 -91.639868` How do I keep values i.e. the coordinates together AND have them separated by a comma? Is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the dict_item?  It looks like the value in another dict.

Comment: I have no dict_item defined anywhere, its only being used right there.

Comment: `dict_item` is simply one item of `MySQL_Dict`. What is needed to provide you with correct answer, and what would improve this question, would be to add example of this `MySQL_Dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to format it on back-end and pass it the jinja in the way you want. In fact its better to put complex logic on the back-end not the front-end *performs better and in jinja's case you don't have to pass in python methods so it's cleaner... other templating frameworks like tornados include all of pythons base functions so you don't have to pass them in like the example below*.  Another way to do it is to pass the `str.join`, `len`, and `range` method to jinja e.x `join=str.join, len=len, range=range` then... *and I'm guessing MySQL_Dict is a 2d array, hence the double for loop*

```
<p>
  {% for dict_item in MySQL_Dict %} // dict_item == [{}, {}, ...]
    {% for i in range(len(dict_item)) %} // dict_item[i] == {some object}
      {{",".join(dict_item[i]["latitude"], dict_item[i]["longitude"])}}
     {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

Comment: Ok, good point. I'll try it on the back end. That's where it would end up eventually anyway. The code you wrote ended up giving me a 500 error, btw, just an FYI not to be rude :)

Comment: Its not a problem hard to test the code without all the information as i cant run it myself, but the base logic remains true. If you figure out the issue with the code above and edit I'll glady make the changes

Comment: Thank you! I used your logic and your suggestion and moved all the computation to the back end and then just passed the values to the templates. Much easier and way less confusing with the Jinja templates. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :-) happy to help